# Install mysql-server version 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Tags: server, mysql

I have a test VM with mysql-server version 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

I want to setup another test VM with the same version of mysql-server, but apt-get is not able to find the repository for this version of the package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server=5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Version '5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1' for 'mysql-server' was not found
```

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`mysql-server version 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` is not available anymore in Ubuntu repositories. You have to manually install it.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/6451356/+files/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/6451356/+files/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/186808649/mysql-common_5.5.40-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-common_5.5.40-0ubuntu1_all.deb mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: easier than my method. +1

Comment: How do you get the URL for this .deb package? there is a dependency on mysql-common, the version for which there is no package in ubuntu repository. I need to do a similar wget for mysql-common

Comment: My bad, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks hg8. But I still have some unresolved dependencies. It would be helpful if you let me know the method to get the repository URL for a specific version of a package, that needs to be passed to wget

Comment: What dependencies are you missing ? I used Google : <package name> <package version> launchpad...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching and downloading the required package from the internet, you can do is backup the current installed pack (which is what you want) from `test VM` and then install it in newer VM

Now boot to your (older) test VM (where mysql is installed), open up new terminal and type copy-paste these lines one by one:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack fakeroot
mkdir ~/dpkg-repack; cd ~/dpkg-repack
fakeroot -u dpkg-repack $(dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1 | grep mysql)
```

Now you will get `deb` packages of MySQL server in `dpkg-repack` folder, now copy them to your newer VM, and put them, say in `mysql` folder

```
cd mysql
sudo dpkg -i -- *.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -i -- *.deb
```